# Hashmap in App Engine Entity class

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I created an entity in App engine endpoint with Hashmap as one property. I am using Objectify for persistence. I have successfully generated client library for android. But when I am trying to use it in android, instead of accepting my hashmap, its asking for JsonMap. Is Hashmap allowed in entity class? If yes, how should I access or save it using cloud endpoints.

```
@Entity
public class MyData {
    @Id
    Long id;
    HashMap<String, Object> userInfo;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Object> getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }

    public void setUserInfo(HashMap<String, Object> userInfo) {
        this.userInfo = new HashMap<>(userInfo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, You have to use interface 'Map' in your entity class. Different API's use different type of implementation maps to hold the records. Example, Hibernate use 'PersistenceMap'. Like that API you use may use different map. But anyway, Ultimately that have to implement java.util.Map interface. So, You have to use the interface 'Map' to declare your reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your entity contains a `HashMap`, Objectify will persist that ([docs](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#maps)) as an `EmbeddedEntity`, so storing it shouldn't be a problem. The question is really how you serialise and deserialise this property of your entity.

What is the `JsonMap` class you refer to and what is 'asking for it'?  Are you using the generated Android library for your Cloud Endpoints?

You may find you need to create a [custom transformer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer) (`@ApiTransform`) for your endpoint to serialise your entity into a form that can be used to create your `JsonMap`.  Or you could read it as a `JsonObject` and deserialise it yourself.  It depends on how predictable the contents of your HashMap are (does it have a known set of keys?).

Comment: Yes I am using generated library for android and in that instead of parameter of hashmap, its asking me for a JsonMap object.